# How return back info from a child to parent in a NavigationController

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I wonder what is the proper way to get back some message from a child view.

I have a object that is edited in the child view. I wanna see in the TableView their modifications.

However, I don't know a clean way to do it (I don't like a singleton here).

Is possible get notified when the Child view dissapear and get some info on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also issue a notification (using NSNotificationCenter) that the parent would be subscribed to listen for - that has the side benefit that other classes could be notified as well.

But if it's a pretty strict relationship where only the sub view and master table will care, you probably should set your table view controller as a delegate of the subview and have the subview call the delegate directly (a protocol as mentioned is a good idea for something like this).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `UIViewController` notifications [`viewWillDisappear:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear:) and [`viewDidDisappear:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidDisappear:) to be notified right before a certain `UIView` is about to disappear and right after it disappears respectively.  Note that most of the various UIKit objects (including `UITableView`) are subclasses of `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the "correct" way would be to implement a custom protocol in the view's controller (probably navigation controller in your case) or the application delegate and have the child view communicate using it when it gets the `viewWillDisappear` and/or `viewWillDisappear` notifications (as mentioned in Adam's reply). Similarly, in the parent view you can refresh the necessary information in the `viewWillAppear` handler.

This way, the parent view is getting its data from the delegate and not directly from a specific child view, which maintains MVC in your design.